# How do I navigate (push) to a page in Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I've followed the documentation for Ionic 2 and couldn't find the way to push/modal a page.

I followed the tutorial, but when I click on the button nothing happens.

The official [guide](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation) didn't explain Page Navigation too well.

Can someone explain the process?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Creating a New Page**

If you want to add new page to the project you need to do it on command prompt. So you need to run below command after changing into your project directory (cd yourProject )

```
ionic g page about
```

The CLI will generate the HTML, TypeScript, and SCSS files for your new page in a new directory under app\pages.

[image]

**Add new page to `app.module.ts` File**

Add declarations of my Page into `app.modules.ts` file. Something Like this ;-

```
   import {AboutPage} from '../pages/about/about';
      @NgModule({
        declarations: [
          MyApp,
          HomePage,
          AboutPage // Add New Page
        ],
        imports: [
          IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
        ],
        bootstrap: [IonicApp],
        entryComponents: [
          MyApp,
          HomePage,
          AboutPage //Add New Page
        ],
        providers: []
      })
  export class AppModule {}
```

**Navigating From Home to About**

To navigate from home page to newly created about page, you will need to import `AboutPage` class into `home.ts` file for use in `HomePage` class.

```
import {AboutPage} from '../about/about';
```

Next you need to create button function on `home.ts`

```
showProfilePage() {
    this.navCtrl.push(AboutPage);
}
```

Next in `home.html` template, we can add a button with on click and navigate to `aboutPage.html`.

```
 <button (click)="showProfilePage()>Go To About</button>
```

And add some content to about template

**Serve**

Next, in the CLI, run ionic serve to view app in the browser:

```
ionic serve --lab
```

Now you can check the navigation functionality in Ionic 2. Cheers !!!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is in a very raw state at the moment. Ionic just came out of beta and there are many breaking changes in the rc version. The documents are being revamped as we speak.

I would recommend [Josh's blog](http://www.joshmorony.com/tag/ionic2/) to learn some basics on Ionic.

And a direct link to the navigation: 
[A Simple Guide to Navigation in Ionic 2](http://www.joshmorony.com/a-simple-guide-to-navigation-in-ionic-2/)

Good luck!